# Django and waypoints Infinite scroll not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have tried all the answers on stack and the infinite scroll is  still not working. My home.html is still displaying the pagination. I suspect the problem is with jquery or the js files or with how the static file is loaded?

Here is my home.html:

```
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<div class="infinite-container">
    {% for post in posts %}

        <div class="infinite-item">
            <article class="media content-section">
              <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                  <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d,  Y" }}</small>
                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>

              </div>

            </article>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="d-flex d-none position-fixed" style="top:35vh;left:46vw">
    <button class="btn btn-primary loading">
        <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
        Please wait...
    </button>
</div>

<!--pagination logic -->

<div class="col-12">
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>

<script src="/static/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/infinite.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
        element: $('.infinite-container')[0],

        offset: 'bottom-in-view',

        onBeforePageLoad: function () {
            $('.loading').show();
        },
        onAfterPageLoad: function () {
            $('.loading').hide();
        }

    });
</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

In my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [Path(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

The directory of my js files.

[image]

I have added the following within my base.html at the bottom.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

here is my class based view in view.py:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
```

Comment: could you please share your views ? the js files should be called like this `<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow Hi, I have addedmy views. And I got an error: Could not parse the remainder: ''js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' from ''js/jquery.waypoints.min.js'

Comment: have you exactly write what i wrote ?

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow No it doesn't work I got an error: Could not parse the remainder: ''js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' from ''js/jquery.waypoints.min.js'

Comment: could you please show the screen shot of your template ?